# Yahoo Widgets - crashing - clean uninstall

Tags: macos, widgets

Anyone remember Konfabulator / Yahoo Widgets? Anyone still use it/ them?

Well, I do… to track my IP, and put rotating pictures on my desktop. Pretty low-level stuff, but it's been part of my desktop UX for a decade.

Trouble is, something has gone rotten. The app(lette?) itself spontaneously quits, and the pop-out pref bar disappears, while the widgets themselves continue running. My rotating pictures in Picture Frame present, but they've walked down my screen. Typically I would occasionally open prefs and move them back up. Now I'm unable.

As a fix, I tried simply deleting the package and reinstalling, but it persists in flaking on me. I searched root and user /Library and /Preferences for tell-tale associated files to kill to no avail.

Anyone have any suggestions on how to diagnose / and fix? I'd be happy to step away from it if anyone has a suggested replacement that will run in the background, and rotate through images in a user defined directory.

For better or worse I'm running Lion on a 2 x 2 GHz Dual Core Intel Xeon Mac Pro Tower.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

System Prefs > Desktop & Screensaver > Desktop can rotate pictures from any specified folder, natively - no widget required.

[image]

Tracking your IP can be done with many tools - this one from dynDNS might do the trick [not something I've ever used as mine is static]  [Dyn Updater](http://dyn.com/apps/updater-mac/)

Screen-fill options as below...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of this capability of the OS, but this suggestion doesn't address my needs. 

The images that rotate through using Picture Frame are always pinned upper left. If the image is portrait format, it fills from top to bottom, not the entire screen. If landscape format it fills ~half the width of the screen, but not full depth.

Comment: none of the screen-fill options work for you? [added as edit] Not that I use any of it - I've had the same Starfish desktop for over 10 years ;-)

Comment: Sorry, no, unfortunately the choices are too limited to be of use. That's probably why Picture Frame was developed.